# MySQL - ordering by something not ASC or DESC

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Say I have a table of flowers with associated colors. Is it possible to get a list of flowers and order them by, say, `Yellow` first, then `Blue`, then `Red`. Basically, I want to specify a list of values and order the result by those values. Possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use FIND_IN_SET:

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(column, 'Yellow,Blue,Red')
```

..or the ANSI CASE statement:

```
ORDER BY CASE column
           WHEN 'Yellow' THEN 1
           WHEN 'Blue' THEN 2
           WHEN 'Red' THEN 3
         END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a field in colors table for `sort_order` and and provide values according to the sort requirement. In the query you can use `ORDER BY sort_order ASC`

I am expecting that you want to order it according to a dynamic requirement not explicitly for these three colors mentioned. This will allow you complete flexibility to manage the sort order.

Comment: How does adding a column solve the problem when sometimes I need to order (Yellow, Blue, Red), sometimes (Blue, Yellow, Red), sometimes (Red, Yellow, Blue), ....

Comment: THe 'sort_order' field should store that hierarchy at which you need to sort. For eg. the value of color and 'sort_order' filed should be as follows when you want to sort (Blue, Yellow, Red),
Blue - 1
Yellow - 2
Red - 3

WHen you want to sort (Red, Yellow, Blue)

Blue - 3
Yellow - 2
Red - 1

This will help you to modify the sort order without editing the php code. At a higher end, you an provide an web provision to manage the sort order in a page so that when ever the user/admin want to change the  order. This is how it is handled on high end web sites.

Answer (score 2):

My choice would be using the [`FIELD(str, str1, str2, ...)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function.

> Returns the index (position) of str in
>   the str1, str2, str3, ... list.
>   Returns 0 if str is not found.

So you could use the return value to order your list of results:

```
ORDER BY FIELD (color, 'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Red')
```

If you want to reverse the order, just add `DESC`.